# Silverlight: Workaround for absence of clientaceesspolicy.xml file

Tags: .net, silverlight-3.0

I have a silverlight 3 application that is required to call a web service to display some data.

the web service is hosted on a remote machine.

unfortunatley the web service does not have

> clinetaccesspolicy.xml

file that allows silverlight applications to call the service, so I can't get the application to work.

is there is any workaround for this problem ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create a proxy web service that runs on the server hosting the Silverlight app. The Silverlight app hits the proxy service that in turn accesses the real web service and returns the results to the client.

Comment: Thanks alot, it seems that this is the only solution